# Capture Result of Input - Display Dialog

Tags: applescript

**How to store the result of input in a variable ?**

For exemplo:

```
display dialog "Insert Number" default answer "1" buttons{"Save"} default button 1

-- Result: {button returned:"OK", text returned:"1"}
```

How to capture the result and declare as the value of a variable?

> *set number to text returned as string*

**^ It doesn't work.**

Help ? =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set userResponse to text returned of (display dialog "Insert Number" default answer "1" buttons {"Save"} default button 1)
```